# Invoke different server-side actions on clicking different buttons in a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

Can I get which button is clicked in the jquery dialog(if 'OK' is clicked or 'Cancel' is clicked) in my spring controller?? I am doing response.sendRedirect from the controller with a querystring, which i use to check for a condition to show the jquery dialog box. I need to return to this controller function with the value of which button is clicked. Is this possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Use the jQuery ajax capabilities and invoke a controller method based on that. For example map one method as `@RequestMapping("/foo/ok")` and the other as `/cancel`, and invoke that URL with `$.post(..)`